# How to access this.state from a function inside componentDidMount in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

`this.state` is undefined when I try to use it inside a function within `componentDidMount`.  `this` is referring to the component within `componentDidMount`, but not when it is called from the nested function.  I have tried binding this to to the function but have not had any luck.  I am using React Native, but I believe this applies to React in general.  Here is `componentDidMount`:

```js
componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.state); //is state of the Component
    //this.state.foos is an array
    var foosRef = firebase.database().ref('foos');
    foosRef.on('child_added', function(child){
      console.log(this.state); //is undefined
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {foos: prevState.push(child) }
      })

    }).bind(this)

  }
```

I currently have the following in my constructor:

```
this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
```

I also tried binding `this` at the end of the callback, instead of after `.on` but that does not work either.

The error is:

```
TypeError: prevState.push is not a function. (In 'prevState.push(child)', prevState.push is undefined)
```

`state` is not a property of `this`.

I know you shouldn't mutate `prevState`, but I was previously doing

```
this.state.foos.push(child)
```

and haven't looked up the syntax for adding an element as a copy of the original.

Comment: Have you tried to assign it to a separate variable, or use an arrow function?

Comment: I tried assigning to separate var, will try arrow now

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This seems like way too "hackish" to be a good solution for my taste

Comment: trying to set the listener to update the state whenever a child is added to the database.  what is the best practice?  I know I am  trying to do Model/Controller logic from the view but this is my first react project and I don't want to introduce something like redux just yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is the context of 'this' within your handler function is not your component's definition.  You can solve this in one of three ways:

1. before calling foosRef.on, add

   ```js
   let my = this;
   ```

then reference "my" inside your inline handler function instead of "this".

OR,
2. move your inline handler function to a standalone member of your component class, e.g.:

```js
function foosRefOnHandler(child){
  console.log(this.state); //is undefined
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {foos: prevState.push(child) }
  }
```

then, you would have to change your foosRef.on call to bind that method:

```js
foosRef.on('child_added', this.foosRefOnHandler.bind(this));
```

OR,
3. using an inline arrow function instead of handler, e.g.:

```js
foosRef.on('child_added', (child) => {
  console.log(this.state); //is undefined
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {foos: prevState.push(child) }
  })

})
```